# Why is my of Common Lisp Web program execution can not

Tags: web, lisp

```
; 一些辅助函数
(require :asdf)
(defun loadlib (mod)
  (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op mod))

(defun reload ()
  (load "web.lisp"))
(defun restart-web ()
  (progn
    (reload)
    (start-web)))

; load 需要的库  
(loadlib :html-template)
(loadlib :hunchentoot)

; 设置 hunchentoot 编码
(defvar *utf-8* (flex:make-external-format :utf-8 :eol-style :lf))
(setq hunchentoot:*hunchentoot-default-external-format* *utf-8*)
; 设置url handler 转发表
(push (hunchentoot:create-prefix-dispatcher "/hello" 'hello) hunchentoot:*dispatch-table*)

; 页面控制器函数
(defun hello ()
  (setf (hunchentoot:content-type*) "text/html; charset=utf-8")
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (html-template:fill-and-print-template
     #p"index.tmpl"
     (list :name "Lisp程序员")
     :stream stream)))
; 启动服务器
(defun start-web (&optional (port 4444))
  (hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:acceptor :port port)))
```

template index.tmpl：

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">  
<html>  
  <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
    <title>Test Lisp Web</title>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
    <h1>Lisp web开发实例</h1>  
    hi, <!-- TMPL_VAR name -->  
  </body>  
</html>
```

When I visited http://localhost:4444/hello
always reported 500 errors, I suspect that the template path, 
my operating system is windows, 
do not know how to write this path.web.lisp with index.tmpl below on the same directory

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question is "did you evaluate `start-web`"? It's probably a "yes", but note that you do actually need to call `start` in order to get your server listening to the appropriate port. If you're getting the Hunchentoot error page, this isn't the problem.

How is `fill-and-print-template` defined? If it expects an absolute pathname, you may need to do `(merge-pathnames "index.tmpl")` instead of passing the relative path.

There are a few things you can do in general to make lisp web-development go more easily for you.

- consider [defining yourself a package](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html). That will let you selectively import symbols instead of prefixing each outside symbol with its source package. It will also let you load your own project more easily.
- consider using [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) instead of defining your own `load-lib`. It lets you easily install and load external librares (AFAIK, if the library you specify is already installed, `ql:quickload` falls through to `asdf:load-op` in any case)
- take a look at [cl-who](http://weitz.de/cl-who/), which I find to be a lot friendlier than HTML templating the hard way, as you're doing
- consider using `hunchentoot:easy-acceptor` and `define-easy-handler` to define your pages (it's a little bit of syntactic sugar to let you define a handler function and simultaneously push the appropriate dispatcher onto `*dispatch-table*`)
- when debugging Hunchentoot apps, it's helpful to `(setf hunchentoot:*catch-errors-p* nil)` (or `(setf hunchentoot:*show-lisp-errors-p* t)`, depending on your preference) in order to get better debugging information.

Comment: Thank you！My problem really lies in the path, modify the path.